# Sum of column based on <xsl:choose> statement in a data view?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, data-view-web-part

I have a column in a SharePoint 2010 dataview that is as follows:

```
<td>
  <xsl:variable name="CurrentYear" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(ddwrt:Today()),1033,'yyyy')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="YearOfWork" select="$thisNode/@Year"/>
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="number($YearOfWork) = number($CurrentYear) - 1">
           <xsl:value-of select="number(@_x004a_an116)"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="number($YearOfWork) + 1 = number($CurrentYear) - 1">
           <xsl:value-of select="number(@_x004a_an1)"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="number($YearOfWork) + 2 = number($CurrentYear) - 1">
           <xsl:value-of select="number(@_x004a_an1)"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="number(0.00)"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</td>
```

I want to get the sum of the values that are displayed in this  on each row. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack using JavaScript in a Calculated Column, since you can't use CSR/JSLink in SP2010

This works in all SP versions, not in the new SPOnline Modern Experiences

Step by step instructions at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Sum

```
="<div style=""color:"
 & IF(    [Rate]<[Buy]   ,"red","green")
 & """>"
 & DOLLAR(   [Qty]*[Rate]   )
 & "</div>"
 & "<div class=""vmSums"" style=""display:none;font-weight:bold;border-top:1px solid black;""></div>"
 & "<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
 & "var TBODY=this;TBODY=this;while(TBODY.tagName!='TBODY'){TBODY=TBODY.parentNode};"
 & "var dataSum='data-vmSum',dataCnt='data-vmCount',total=value="
 &    [Qty]*[Rate]   
 & ",count=0;"
 & "if(TBODY.getAttribute(dataSum)){"
 & "total=parseFloat(TBODY.getAttribute(dataSum))+value;"
 & "count=~~TBODY.getAttribute(dataCnt)+1}"
 & "TBODY.setAttribute(dataSum,Number(Math.round(total+'e2')+'e-2').toFixed(2));"
 & "TBODY.setAttribute(dataCnt,count);"
 & "window.clearTimeout(window.vmSumFunc);"
 & "window.vmSumFunc=window.setTimeout((function(){"
 & "var lastrownr=~~TBODY.getAttribute(dataCnt),"
 & "last=document.getElementsByClassName('vmSums').item(lastrownr),"
 & "total=parseFloat(TBODY.getAttribute(dataSum)).toFixed(2);"
 & "last.textContent='$'+total;"
 & "last.style.display='block';"
 & "}), 100)"
 & "}"">"
```